# Fullpage.js sections not working

Tags: javascript, html, fullpage.js

I recently installed "FullPage.js" to my site. I figured out how to get the slides working but the sections won't for some reason. Can't seem to find anything in the console.

```
    <div class="section" id="section1">
        <div class="slide active">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <span class="line"></span>
                <div class="title">HOME</div>
                <span class="line2"></span>
                <div class="post">
                    <h1>Hey I'm <strong>Matt Hunzinger</strong></h1><br>
                    <p>I like making flat designs that <strong>elevate</strong> my client's businesses<br><br><span class="toSlide" data-index="3">Contact Me</span></p> <br> <hr> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
                    <div class="grid">
                        <span class="toSlide" data-index="2">
                            <div class="hex" id="about">
                                <li>About Me</li>
                                <img src="about.png">
                            </div>
                        </span>
                        <span class="toSlide" data-index="3">
                            <div class="hex" id="contact">
                                 <img src="email.png">
                            </div>
                        </span>
                        <span class="toSlide" data-index="4">
                            <div class="hex" id="about">
                                <li>Work</li>
                                <img src="about.png">
                            </div>
                        </span>
                       <br>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="section" id="section2">
       <div class="slide">
           <h1> hello all</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.fullpage({
        resize: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you including all the needed files? (jQuery libraries, plugin, css...) Could you add all your page HTML ?

Comment: how does one include those files?

Comment: do those libraries have to be in the `/var/www/html` folder?