# ensure all prerequisite components in .js file // example page malfunction

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I tried to setup just the basic index.html page, but seems that it's completely broken.

I can't find any questions where people had similar issue.

The page renders looking as if it's merely ill-formatted HTML.

Maybe I have to include some additional libraries? Link something in a different way? In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461702/fullpage-js-sections-not-working?rq=1) Alvaro, the createur, himself seems to say as much, but doesn't specify how.

Thus far I've directly copied the example from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6602KMtq1Y) but it was completely not working, then I switched and implemeted the [demo page](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/examples/demoPage.html), still no improvement.

See [my site](http://btwnthelin.es/) maybe that could be some indication of the problem.

Is there any prerequisite I need to install to make this file work in [this way](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/):

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>fullPage.js One Page Scroll Sites</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Alvaro Trigo Lopez" />
    <meta name="description" content="fullPage plugin by Alvaro Trigo. Create fullscreen pages fast and simple. One page scroll like iPhone website." />
    <meta name="keywords"  content="fullpage,jquery,alvaro,trigo,plugin,fullscren,screen,full,iphone5,apple" />
    <meta name="Resource-type" content="Document" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.fullPage.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="examples.css" />


    <style>
        /* Sections
         * --------------------------------------- */
        #section0 img,
        #section1 img{
            margin: 20px 0 0 0;
        }
        #section2 img{
            margin: 20px 0 0 52px;
        }
        #section3 img{
            bottom: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: -420px;
        }
        .intro p{
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }
        .twitter-share-button{
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 99;
            right: 149px;
            top: 9px;
        }
    </style>
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             var console = { log: function() {} };
        </script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="examples.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#ccddff'],
                anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', 'lastPage'],
                menu: '#menu',
                scrollingSpeed: 1000
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>


<select id="demosMenu">
  <option selected>Choose Demo</option>
  <option id="backgrounds">Background images</option>
  <option id="backgroundVideo">Background video</option>
  <option id="gradientBackgrounds">Gradient backgrounds</option>
  <option id="backgroundsFixed">Fixed fullscreen backgrounds</option>
  <option id="looping">Looping</option>
  <option id="noAnchor">No anchor links</option>
  <option id="scrollingSpeed">Scrolling speed</option>
  <option id="easing">Easing</option>
  <option id="callbacks">Callbacks</option>
  <option id="css3">CSS3</option>
  <option id="continuous">Continuous scrolling</option>
  <option id="normalScroll">Normal scrolling</option>
  <option id="scrollBar">Scroll bar enabled</option>
  <option id="scrolling">Scroll inside sections and slides</option>
  <option id="navigationV">Vertical navigation dots</option>
  <option id="navigationH">Horizontal navigation dots</option>
  <option id="fixedHeaders">Fixed headers</option>
  <option id="apple">Apple iPhone demo (animations)</option>
  <option id="oneSection">One single section</option>
  <option id="responsive">Responsive</option>
  <option id="methods">Methods</option>
</select>

<ul id="menu">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="#firstPage">First slide</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">Second slide</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage"><a href="#3rdPage">Third slide</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="4thpage"><a href="#4thpage">Fourth slide</a></li>
</ul>


<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section " id="section0">
        <h1>fullPage.js</h1>
        <p>Create Beautiful Fullscreen Scrolling Websites</p>
        <img src="imgs/fullPage.png" alt="fullPage" />
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section1">
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="intro">
                <h1>Create Sliders</h1>
                <p>Not only vertical scrolling but also horizontal scrolling. With fullPage.js you will be able to add horizontal sliders in the most simple way ever.</p>
                <img src="imgs/slider.png" alt="slider" />
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="intro">
                <img src="imgs/1.png" alt="simple" />
                <h1>Simple</h1>
                <p>Easy to use. Configurable and customizable.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="intro">
                <img src="imgs/2.png" alt="Cool" />
                <h1>Cool</h1>
                <p>It just looks cool. Impress everybody with a simple and modern web design!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="intro">
                <img src="imgs/3.png" alt="Compatible" />
                <h1>Compatible</h1>
                <p>Working in modern and old browsers too! IE 8 users don't have the fault of using that horrible browser! Lets give them a chance to see your site in a proper way!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section2">
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>Example</h1>
            <p>HTML markup example to define 4 sections.</p>
            <img src="imgs/example2.png" alt="example" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section3">
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>Working On Tablets</h1>
            <p>
                Designed to fit to different screen sizes as well as tablet and mobile devices.
                <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            </p>
        </div>
        <img src="imgs/tablets.png" alt="tablets" />
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the index page on your site you have links to the javascript files e.g.

```
<script src="vendors/jquery.easings.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
```

Neither of these files that you refer to are in the location that is specified, i.e. the browser cannot find the files to download.

If the files are supposed to be in a directory "vendor" then there should be a "vendor" directory underneath the directory of the index.html file. The jquery.fullPage.js file should be in the same directory as the index.html file.

The above said, try to keep all your js files in a single directory or it get very confusing.

Comment: ah, ok cool. so the root then is my `/var/www/html` where my `index.html` file is located, and everything needs to start from there? It seems like java class path, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the JavaScript console in your browser and you will see that your scripts are failing to load. So either you forgot to upload them or the paths in your script tags are wrong:

[image: 404s]

Comment: how do i set the paths? it's like class paths? what is a javascript console?

Comment: With `path` I mean the `src` attribute on your `<script>` tags, I think Mr Morphe explained it more clearly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29876640/1240061